# Why does mouse-wheel scrolling stop working on a site, only some times?

Tags: html, css, browser, scroll, mousewheel

My website sometimes bugs, making it impossible to scroll the page using the mouse wheel, touchpad or finger. Dragging the scrollbar, pressing space or pressing page-up/down does work.

Any suggestions on what it could be, or how one would go about fixing such a bug?

There dosn't seem to be any specific action or page connected to the bug, it only happens about once every other day, and has happened on several devices, OS-es and browsers (even iPads and Android, IE11 and firefox).

Even hard-refreshing the page, or browsing to another page on the same domain dosn't fix the bug.
I've tried disabling Javascript in my browser, clearing all site data, scrolling with the touchpad instead of mouse, have checked the "html" and "body" elements for CSS rules that might block scrolling and even removed all html from the page and replaced it with mockup html.

I know the question is vague, with no example code, and I can't give an URL.
If anyone can point me in a direction, or have any tips, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do face the same situation, and what I do in such situations is:

- Press the mouse wheel.
- Move the cursor up and down on the page, still holding the wheel, till the page scrolls.
- Let go of the mouse wheel.

You will now be able to scroll using the mouse wheel.

P.S: I'll edit this answer after some time with pictures and more explainations, till then, this should work.